# Google Play service is not working properly in my Android game

Tags: android, google-play-services, google-play-games

I am using Google play service in my android game. I already linked my app to my Google Play Developer Console.

When i am trying to run my app through USB debugging, I can sign into Google Play Games successfully and it is working perfectly, but whenever i am installing my app from the Google Play Store, signing into Google Play Games is giving me **"Failed to sign in..."**

Where am I making a mistake?

Comment: what is the logcat error?

Comment: When i running my app from android studio directly. it's successfully connecting to google play game. logcat showing successfully connected.

Comment: i assume, your phone restrict the background service while using mobile data. Try to enable the background service, or use it in wifi to connect play service. i had this prob in my device, so that suggested. this is my guess.

Comment: it's working when i run app from android studio. but not working when install from play store. it's not working on other device also

Comment: previously it was working but suddenly this failed to sign in error

Comment: It's fixed, I answered my own question

Answer (score 3):

SHA1 fingerprint in Android Studio is for debug-key store, 
on releasing SHA1 fingerprint, it gives a fingerprint for the release key store and then add the 2nd app in Google play game console (Linked Apps->add the new app)

**You can find the full answer with explanation in this link **
https://chandruscm.wordpress.com/tag/how-to-obtain-sha1-signing-certificate-fingerprint-from-android-studio/